Precision issues when combining scale instances node with translate instances (or offset instances)
In version 4.2, I have a geonode network that taking data from some csv files, creates a grid of vertical bars.
Problem is that I have to scale those bars (instance is a cube) to get their height correctly. When you do that, the bars get centered vertically around zero, and their height modified and all is correct.
But now I need all the bars to have their base aligned at 0. So I have to either translate them vertically with a translate instances node or offset them vertically with a set position node.
In both cases I get the same problem. Due to apparently some lack of precision, all the bars yes get their bases aligned at 0 more or less, but not exactly. Low bars seem to be ok, but high or very high bars stick their bottom parts a bit below 0. And this "almost" aligned at 0 produces tons of problems for me later.
How can I ensure that translating or offsetting the bars does not introduce precision issues so that they all get correctly and perfectly aligned to 0 in their bases?

You seem to be experiencing issues with geometry nodes but you did not disclose your node tree, show us your scene or illustrate what you are trying to achieve, which makes it impossible for us to help. Please edit your post and provide images or GIFs illustrating the scene, node tree and any relevant settings that helps us diagnose the issue, rather than guess blindly what you are trying to achieve

Scaling geometry is simply multiplying the position components by appropriate scale components (same letter). So in order to not move a vertex vertically by scaling, its Z position has to be zero.
The simplest way to achieve this is to move a cube up by half of its height:

Then all cubes are aligned to the $z=0$ plane and scaling them won't move the bottom away from that plane:


Haha, just the answer I was preparing right now. The old man is too slow, as always :D Just for demonstration purposes I added an Index Switch with different values as a substitute for his CSV file data to scale a row of instances: instances with different heights scaled from Z = 0
